# Adding MSB and LSB to get 0-511

Tags: midi, max-msp-jitter

I'm trying to get 9 bits out of a MIDI controller. According to the manual, the position of a fader on the MIDI controller is sent out as 9 bits, which would make it 0-511.

In my software (Max/MSP), the MSB comes in as only 7 bits (0-127) and the LSB flickers between 0/64 generally and occasionally I see 32 and 96.

I think I need to do some bit shifting and then add the MSB and LSB somehow to get the full 0-511.

Any ideas?

```
from the manual:

MSB=0 M M M M M M M
LSB=0 L L 0 0 0 0 0

The position is sent out with 9 bits of accuracy. The 2 least significant bits can be ignored for 7-bit accuracy.
```

Answer (score 1):

MIDI data values can only use 7 bits, so it's spread the most significant 7 to that first CC data byte, and the last couple bits to the next CC data byte.

If you convert the least significant bits, possible values are `0`, `32`, `64`, and `96` as you have seen.  But of course, those aren't meant to be taken out of context.

Assemble your bits like this:

```
0000 000M MMMM MMLL
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please clarify what you mean by "assemble my bits"? The data is coming into Max/MSP as numbers ie: 176 32 0. Do I need to convert it to binary or something?

Comment: @user2313418 I'm not sure how to do it in Max, but essentially you need to bit-shift your MSB value two positions to the left (i.e. multiply it by `4`), bit-shift your LSB value five positions to the right (i.e. divide it by `32`), and then add those values together.